# De-humidify a fridge

Tags: refrigerator

I live in an apartment that was furnished with a fridge, but I find that it tends to be rather humid, causing condensation on my veg and consequently spoiling my veg more quickly. There isn't a humidity control, nor are there humidity-controlled drawers for use. Any suggestions on maintaining a lower level of humidity in the fridge?

I'm considering playing with quantities of desiccant to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check the temperature: it should be around 37°F (3°C). If the temperature checks, look around the door for an air leak. Sometimes the door seal gets loose or dries out, letting the outside humidity in, which then condense on the food making it easier for bacteria to grow and spoil the food.

If you still find it too humid you could try a box of [Polar King](http://www.coolerking.com)